# chrome extensions block from specific domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to disallow chrome extensions from a specific domain.

For example I want extensions that I install run on on other domain, but on the domain `test.com` I want no extensions at all.

I tried `tools->extensions` but there I can just disallow from incognito and some part of extensions everywhere.

Is it actually possible?

Comment: If your talking about extensions that you have installed and not one youve made yourself, then the answer is no.  Pitty, kinda woulda thought thered by something under Privacy - content settings, but there wasn't.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Extension Automation that handles that for you:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-automation/ghopjgdkodchjclkkfdekhjfomdbakkb

Automatically enables and disables extensions for specified sites. For simpler browsing and better performance.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be taken down. Any alternatives?

Comment: try here https://github.com/moarsel/chrome-extension-automation

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You have to either use incognito mode or create a separate user (chrome menu->Settings->Users) which doesn't have any extensions.

Comment: This is really a sad thing. A lot of extensions asks too wide rights, like a *://*/ access. I don't need nor adblock nor ANY other content scripts on my cell phone operators or banks domains. And both Firefox and Chrome are failing here same way.

Answer (score -1):

The following code disable extensions for http://www.google.co.in/ and enables for other domains, you can customize it as needed; How ever it works only for extensions you create and at all installed instances

[image]

[image]

***manifest.json***

```
{
"name":"Browser Action Demo",
"description":"This Demonstrates Demo of Browser Action",
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"screen.png",
"default_title":"Browser Action Demo"
},
"background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
},
"manifest_version":2,
"version":"1"
}
```

***background.js***

```
function browseraction(){
    chrome.tabs.query({"url":"http://www.google.co.in/"},function (tabs){
        for(i=0;i<tabs.length;i++){
            chrome.browserAction.disable(tabs[i].id);
        }
    });
}
window.onload=browseraction;
```